# JavaMelody error - Monitoring of sql requests and of jdbc connections in GlassFish v4.1

Tags: glassfish-4.1, java-melody

I want to use JavaMelody to monitor the SQL requested by a Glassfish Application Server. There are step-by-step instructions on https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#monitoring-of-sql-requests-and-of-jdbc-connections-in-glassfish-v3

I followed the instructions (I didn't download javamelody-objectfactory.jar but used javamelody-core-1.54.0.jar instead) and I get this error when clicking on the refresh button (javamelody web page) :

server.log :

```
exception while collecting data
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jrobin/core/RrdException
at net.bull.javamelody.Collector.getCounterJRobin(Collector.java:836)
at net.bull.javamelody.Collector.collectJRobinValues(Collector.java:489)
...
```

any idea how to resolve this ?

jrobin-1.5.9.1.jar is installed in the lib folder of glassfish (and in my ear project).

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[javamelody-objectfactory.jar](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/releases/download/javamelody-core-1.49.0/javamelody-objectfactory.jar) (java source included in the jar) and javamelody-core jar file are absolutely different things. The first is to make the datasource monitorable in Glassfish and the second is the monitoring tool itself.

First fix the exception. You should probably put javamelody-core jar and jrobin jar files in your ear project (and not one in lib folder of Glassfish and one in ear).

Then if the monitoring reports don't include SQL monitoring for the datasource declared in Glassfish, use the [javamelody-objectfactory.jar](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/releases/download/javamelody-core-1.49.0/javamelody-objectfactory.jar) including all steps as said in the [doc](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#monitoring-of-sql-requests-and-of-jdbc-connections-in-glassfish-v3).